# how "%1$s" and "%2$s" are converted into String in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Usually , when you use sprintf, you will write down %s and matching actual value like below(" %s " = "p" , "%s" = " #999 "  etc)

```
<?php
  $output = sprintf(
    '<%s style="color:%s">%s</%s>', 
    'p', 
    '#999',
    'Text', 
    'p' 
  ); 
  echo $output;
?>
```

But in register_sidebar() method of wordpress, I know %1$1 and %2$s is coverted into "widgetName-Number"(id) and "widget widget_widgetName"(class) by sprintf.

But I dont know how they converted "%1$1" and "%2$s" into these values??(Because these values are not mentioned in register_sidebar() method)

```
register_sidebar(
     array(
      'name' => 'sidebar', 
      'id' => 'sidebar', 
      'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
      'after_widget' => '</div>',
      'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title">',
      'after_title' => '</div>',
     )
 );
```

Comment: these strings are from wordpress core function. when you use `register_sidebar` you call a **wordpress core** function that has some variables in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is written in wordpress core function named `dynamic_sidebar()`. If you see the function carefully then you will find the follows line of within the function actually converting -

```
$params[0]['before_widget'] = sprintf( $params[0]['before_widget'], $id, $classname_ );
```